# HOW can I list all the possibilities?

Tags: problem-solving

Removing one coin from each of the triangles — more specifically, one a, one b, and one c — forms a pattern (like the example shown).

[image]

Every possibility is listed below (ignore the circles and squares around some of them).

[image]

How can you systematically list all of the possibilities, so that you get that answer?

Comment: the figure should follow some kind of symmetry after the removal of some coins?

Comment: I don't really understand what the space of all the possibilities is. Is the starting picture always the same? (The figure on the left)

Comment: This is not clear at all. Must you choose one coin from each of the three little triangles or could you take $a,b,c$ from a single little triangle?  What are the rules?  I expect that if you write the rules clearly the solution will emerge.

Comment: so you want to list the 27 possibilities? number the $a$ a1, a2, a3 and same for other letters, then take one from each

Comment: Assuming you are asking just for a way of picking one of the three `a` coins, one of the three `b` coins, and one of the three `c` coins with no further restrictions... simply list the numbers $000_3$ to $222_3$ in base $3$ and interpret the number as such a selection... the first digit corresponding to if you took the top copy (0), the bottom left copy (1), or the bottom right copy (2) of `a` respectively, and similarly so for the second digit and third digit...

Comment: @h-squared no, the figure shouldn't follow any kind of simmetry

Comment: @lulu editing the question

Answer (score 0):

We have to derive the underlying structure of the problem, forgetting about the artistic paraphernalia. We have three lines of $a$,$b$, $c$ and should select one element from each numbered line and one element from each letterized column:
$$\left[\matrix{a_1&b_1&c_1\cr a_2&b_2&c_2\cr a_3&b_3&c_3\cr}\right]\ .$$
As in a $3\times3$-determinant there are $6$ ways to do this: Select one object from the first line ($3$ ways), then one allowed element from the second line ($2$ ways) and then the only remaining element from the third line.

You can arrange the admissible selection lexicographically as follows:
$$a_1b_2c_3,\ a_1b_3c_2, \ b_1a_2c_3, \ b_1c_2a_3, \ c_1a_2b_3, \ c_1b_3a_2\ .$$